# Populate a MS Access database in Linux

Tags: linux, ms-access

Is there any way to create an Access / Jet database from within Linux?

I'm trying to feed data from a linux application server (mysql backend) and have not found any tools that let me do this - it seems there should be something.

If I can't create a database, is there a way to insert into an existing Access database file from within Linux?

CLI tool, wrapper to SQL command file, C library, Ruby library, anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a java library called [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) that can write to Access mdb files from any platform that can run a jvm.

Answer (score 1):

[EasySoft](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/) have an ODBC driver that could be used to insert data into an existing MS Access database.

If you can, I would swap Access for [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) (free download), then you can use the [FreeTDS ODBC driver](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/) to talk to it from Linux or one of the other available commercial ODBC drivers to access MS SQL Server from Linux.

Comment: Does SQL Server Express run on Linux? If so, you're just swapping one Windows database for another. If you're running Linux, using Linux databases!

Comment: Linux can talk to SQL server via ODBC and TCP sockets.  But an Access ODBC driver would essentially be an entire implementation of JET, and Linux doesn't have one of those.  So an SQL Server would actually work here.

Comment: This answer does not take "recent" developments (i.e., over the last six years) into account. See [James' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959483/2144390) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179927/2144390) for options.

Comment: @Gord: I hardly think a downvote is justified by the fact that a once correct answer has become out of date.

Answer (score 1):

might be a dumb question, but why access? I have to assume that this data needs to make its way over to Windows at some point?
There might be other ways of solving this problem.
if the access db is going to be used in house, you can setup a connection to MySQL from Access running on windows and get the data that way..
if the data file is going to be disconnected, you could try creating a comma-separated text file with the data, but give it a .xls extension - on a windows machine this will cause it to open in Excel, which many users would be ok with.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to create an Access / Jet database from within Linux?

Absolutely. [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is a free, open-source, pure Java JDBC driver that can create/read/write Access 2000+ databases (read-only for Access 97) on any machine running Java. More information on how to use it with Java can be found here:

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

If you'd rather work with Python then you can use UCanAccess with Jython or JayDeBeApi as illustrated in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614063/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create an access database (mdb file) from scratch, you'll need some Microsoft Office dll, so I think you can forget it.
2. If your idea is to insert/manipulate data in an Access mdb file, you'll need a specific driver for the kind of connexion you want to use. I think your choice will be basically between ODBC and OLEDB. You can then use this connexion to modify your data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), extract it (SELECT) of even manipulate your database structure through DDL instructions (CREATE, DROP, etc).

Comment: re: "If you want to create an access database (mdb file) from scratch, you'll need some Microsoft Office dll, so I think you can forget it." - No longer true, see [James' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959483/2144390) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179927/2144390) for options.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a web service?  You could run an ASP (or whatever) service on a Windows machine, and it could construct the required .mdb file using ODBC.  Then your Linux app could upload the raw data and receive an .mdb in response.

Or alternatively, just run your entire script on Windows.  You can install cygwin and/or ActiveSate perl and access Windows ODBC drivers (including Access) from there.

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible for you to edit your access database in windows so that you use linked tables which are then linked to an external Text File, XML File, HTML Document, etc.?

In Office2007 use the "External Data" tab and then select 'Text File', 'XML File', etc.. Just make sure that you select the radio button 'Link to the data source by creating a linked table.' If you first remove the existing table and create a linked table with the same name you just might fool your application into viewing the text file through Access as a proxy.

This way you could update the external file easily from your linux application and your application should see that data when it interacts with the access database.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Access 2002 on the Linux system using [Crossover Office](https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=564), and automate it from a script.  (For example, you can write some VBScript and execute it using wscript.exe under CrossOver.)

Lately, I'm doing this myself for some databases and it works great.  Email me if you need some help setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

To create an MS Access database on Linux can be done from Windows.

1. Setup a SMB share on Linux
2. On Windows create a mapped drive to your SMB share
3. Create an Access database
   3.1 If you have MS Access installed you can simply create a new database on the share.
   3.2 If you do not have MS Access installed but you have an MS Access ODBC driver on Windows simply create a new Microsoft Access ODBC data source - this will give you the option to create a database.

You could then use as [Easysoft Access ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html) to write data to your database.

Alternatively you could use another Easysoft tool the [Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/index.html). This would let you keep your Access database on Windows but let you make ODBC calls to it from your Linux application.

Answer (score 0):

[MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/)  provides:

- a C library
- a set of command-line tools
- an ODBC driver [unixODBC](for http://www.unixodbc.org/) which in turn has wrappers for other languages

It's free and open source.

Comment: *"It's free and open source."* - And moribund. And broken.