# How do I access a .mdb file from python?

Tags: python, ms-access

I have my database in msacess 2000 .mdb format which I downloaded from the net and now I want to access that database from my program which is a python script.
Can I call tables from my programs??
it would be very grateful if anyone  of you please suggest me what to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559659/accessing-a-jet-mdb-database-in-python will help you.

Answer (score 4):

For whoever pass by, another option is using [mdbtools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools) - which can export the MDB database to a re-usable format, like CSV- check: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=168

If you don't need to update the mdb file, just to import legacy data, doing something akin to the recipe on the link above is easier than get pyodbc working properly and, it does not require access to a Windows machinne

Answer (score 2):

If you work on Windows, then you can use ODBC and use `odbc` module (ActiveState Python has it by default, this is part of win32 extensions), or `pyodbc` module. Have a look at answers to: [How to connect pyodbc to an Access (.mdb) Database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251702/how-to-connect-pyodbc-to-an-access-mdb-database-file/)

If you use Jython you can use JDBC-ODBC bridge:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")
db = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\Nwind.mdb', usr, passwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an ODBC DSN wit hthis MDB. Python can access ODBC data sources.