# Import MDB table to ACCDB using PYTHON

Tags: python, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am looking for a way to mimic the "Get External Data" in Access 2007 (accdb) using Python. I am trying to import data from a MDB to a ACCDB. Basically I don't want to do this manually each time, but incorporate it into my Python workflow.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559659/accessing-a-jet-mdb-database-in-python

Comment: operating system is Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a Windows-machine:

You can automate the "Get External Data"-task by using VBA. Dive into the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841419) of the TransferX (TransferText...) methods of the DoCmd-Object in VBA. So before using Python, I would recommend you should program a working VBA-solution for your task.

After that, you can try to use the [Win32 Extensions for Python](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html). These offer some COM-Interop classes you could use. Probably this piece of code in Python would be the starter for you:

```
import win32com.client
acc = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
...
```

With this at hand you should be able to transfer your VBA-Code to Python.