# ODBC and JET Databases in Linux

Tags: database, linux, odbc, jet

How can you setup ODBC on Linux for JET Databases?

I've tried with both UNIXOdbc and iODBC but I can't seem to get it to work...

Could somenone provide some guidance?

### Edit

I must open and run some queries on *.mdb files (native Access databases' format). On windows I use Python and the library `pydobc`. I would like to be able to run my code from linux too. I could propably just use mdb-tools to extract the data but I would prefer it if I could directly connect to the database (maybe I will need to add some tables and redistribute the *.mdb file).

Comment: [This][1] question is similar and has some great suggestions in the answers.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256459/populate-a-ms-access-database-in-linux

Comment: @Jim Blizard, thank you! I think though that my question is very specific. Unfortunately I can't change the database...

Answer (score 1):

Its commercial but this should do what you need.

http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html

Comment: thank you Nick, but unfortunately commercial products are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to iODBC you will need an ODBC driver too...

One such ODBC driver is the [OpenLink Multi-tier ODBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/)

Answer (score 0):

Any luck? In case it still does not work, do you have a proper ODBC driver for that database, because ODBC compliant applications do not have to have UnixODBC or anything like that installed. All of that is usually done inside of the application itself which reads the connection string, and reacts properly. If it finds DSN, it needs to find the entry for this DSN, but if you add DRIVER= and this driver is a path to an .so file, it should load the driver without searching for .odbcinst.ini or anything like that.